# RethinkDB - Left join where joined_table.identifier is null?

Tags: rethinkdb

I have two tables in a RethinkDB database that represent a one-to-many relationship. Consider the following two tables:

```
t1
ParentId    Name
1           lorem
2           ipsum
3           dotor
4           sit
5           amet

t2
ChildId ParentId    ChildName
1       1           something
2       3           random
3       5           here
```

On t1, ParentId is the primary key, and on t2, there is a secondary index on ParentId. I want to find which parents don't have a child. The operation in SQL (MSSQL to be exact) looks like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t2.ParentId = t1.ParentId
WHERE t2.ChildId IS NULL

Results:
ParentId    Name
2           ipsum
4           sit
```

How can I accomplish this similar result in RethinkDB? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
r.table('t1').filter(function(parent) {
  return r.table('t2').get_all(parent('ParentId'), {index: 'ParentId'}).count().eq(0);
})
```