# How to delete RethinkDB documents that cannot be joined?

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I have a tables `Person` and `Property`. Each one has its own `id`. In addition, properties have their human owner, hence have a field `person_id` which "points" to the `id` in the `Person` table.

This is an example of three people that have some things. For some reason, person with `id=3` was deleted. However, he/she still owns properties with `id in [4,5,6]`.

```
Person (1k documents)
=====================

{id: 1, name: John, age: 25}
{id: 2, name: Peter, age: 28, pet: cat}
{id: 4, name: Alice}
...

Property (120k documents)
=========================

{id: 1, person_id: 1, name: house}
{id: 2, person_id: 1, name: car, color: blue}
{id: 3, person_id: 2, name: phone}
{id: 4, person_id: 3, name: house}
{id: 5, person_id: 3, name: watch, size: big}
{id: 6, person_id: 3, name: table: material: wood}
...
```

The question is "How to delete the properties documents that no longer have an existing person they belong to?", i.e. in this case "How to delete properties with `id in [4,5,6]`?"

`person_id` is a secondary index.

My thoughs were like somehow extract the properties `id`s that don't match any persons and than delete them. However, I have no idea how to achieve that.

Comment: New to RethinkDB myself, but I think this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29883200/456645. `t1` is `Property`, and `t2` is `Person`.

Comment: @bitsoflogic nice, that works! thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RethinkDB - Left join where joined\_table.identifier is null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872836/rethinkdb-left-join-where-joined-table-identifier-is-null)